# How to change the color of 3D objects in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, 3d, fbx

I have a 3D object with the following code:

```
 {
      materials: [
        {
          name: 'Material_3',
          parameters: [
            {
              baseColor: [
                0.84313700000000003,
                0.72548999999999997,
                0.49803900000000001,
                1,
              ],
            },
            {
              baseColorMap: null,
            },
            {
              normalMap: null,
            },
            {
              interpolatedColor: null,
            },
            {
              metallic: 0,
            },
            {
              metallicMap: null,
            },
            {
              roughness: 0,
            },
            {
              roughnessMap: null,
            },
            {
              opacity: null,
            },
          ],
          source: 'build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/fbx_material.sfm',
        },
        {
          name: 'Material_2',
          parameters: [
            {
              baseColor: [
                0.50196099999999999,
                0.81568600000000002,
                0.57647099999999996,
                1,
              ],
            },
            {
              baseColorMap: null,
            },
            {
              normalMap: null,
            },
            {
              interpolatedColor: null,
            },
            {
              metallic: 0,
            },
            {
              metallicMap: null,
            },
            {
              roughness: 0,
            },
            {
              roughnessMap: null,
            },
            {
              opacity: null,
            },
          ],
          source: 'build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/fbx_material.sfm',
        },
        {
          name: 'Material_1',
          parameters: [
            {
              baseColor: [
                0.792157,
                0.50196099999999999,
                0.67843100000000001,
                1,
              ],
            },
            {
              baseColorMap: null,
            },
            {
              normalMap: null,
            },
            {
              interpolatedColor: null,
            },
            {
              metallic: 0,
            },
            {
              metallicMap: null,
            },
            {
              roughness: 0,
            },
            {
              roughnessMap: null,
            },
            {
              opacity: null,
            },
          ],
          source: 'build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/fbx_material.sfm',
        },
      ],
      model: {
        attributes: [
          'Position',
          'TexCoord',
          'Orientation',
          'BoneIndices',
          'BoneWeights',
        ],
        collision: {},
        file: 'sampledata/box-test.FBX',
        name: 'box-test',
        recenter: 'root',
      },
      version: '0.54:2',
    }
```

The object is 3 cubes, the cubes have names - Material_1, Material_2, Material_3, you need:

-On the first material to impose transparency

-On the second material to impose metallicity

-On the third material to impose self-illumination

P.S. I'm just starting to do 3D in Android Studio, so I don’t know how to do it